# Expanding Qt interface if necessary

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I'm working on a Qt project and I've noticed a persistent problem with some GUI forms. The form   looks fine on KDE (bottom picture) and Windows , but when the app runs on anything GNOME3-based (like Unity or GNOME3 itself) some parts of the form are hidden from view. (Top picture, everything below the Sort Ascending radio button is cut off)

The problem seems to be with how Qt layouts handle large font sizes.  If the user is using normal-sized system font (<= 10pt) everything works fine. If they are using larger fonts, the form is not large enough to accommodate everything. Other forms affected by this bug are merely crowded, but that isn't as serious as having vital controls out of bounds. The layout doesn't want to resize itself to take advantage of new space if I enlarge the dialog. Is there an easy way to make it do this or do I need to hard-code it? Originally the code prevented dialog resizing during runtime, but restoring that functionality didn't fix the bug. Even if the dialog can expand, the problem is the layout won't expand with it.

Up until now, I've made all affected forms oversized to compensate for this bug, but it looks strange to have the dialogs much bigger than they need to be on Windows and KDE systems where the font is the proper size. Is there a way to cause an affected dialog/layout to resize itself so everything fits properly at runtime? If so, how would the program detect it when parts of the GUI are out of bounds?  I would prefer not to force a certain font size (some people may prefer large fonts due to vision problems).

Thanks in advance for help.

[image: Part of the options gets cut off (right below Sort Ascending)]

[image: This is how it's supposed to look]

Comment: I don't know how you have your layout specified, but it sounds like a problem with the layout if it won't expand with the dialog, at least to the point that all controls are visible.

Comment: Caleb Huitt is most probably right. There is something wrong with layouts usage here. Show how do you construct UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix for this is using a different approach when displaying forms. A more dynamic way as I'll describe. I've successfully used this approach on Windows with 96 and very high DPI modes (over 120).

1.
Query the OS and get the user's chosen font for a particular system item; say the font used for the window caption or system dialog boxes. Also you could allow the user to choose their font later if they desired. Use True Type fonts when doing this if possible.

2.
Using that font, construct a string object that you'll use for a label or edit control (I don't know what this is for QT, for Windows it is GetTextExtentPoint32) and pass it to a system function to determine the width and height of the string for your environment.

3.
Given the above value, place the control and dynamically resize the form with the padding all around the control as you like. For buttons you might always add a certain percentage of pixels above and below the button to taste.

4.
For graphical elements like Bitmaps and jpegs, again query the OS for the current DPI settings of the monitor and use larger, pre-made resources. Naturally, all text around theses elements will be dynamically placed on the fly.

Note that on Windows you'll need to mark your exe as high dpi aware using a manifest.

Comment: +1 For labels `QFontMetrics(QApplication::font(), this).boundingRect("My Label")` returns the bounding box for a string using the current paint device's pixel settings.

Comment: This is absolutely wrong not portable approach. The problem is caused by wrongly constructed Qt UI and using system-specific calls will only cause more problems.